# Adding headers to excel file

Tags: asp.net

i am creating an excel file using the datatable as intput to the function.
althought is creatin the excel file it doesnt add the headers. can any one give code to do
so below is the code and the row/colum structure of the excel file..

```
private void ExporttoExcel(DataTable table)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Reports.xls");
    // HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Reports.doc");
    // HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Reports.xlsx");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("head");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("tail");
    // excell_app.createHeaders(5, 2, "Total of Products", "B5", "D5", 2, "YELLOW", true, 10, "n");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<font style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<BR><BR><BR>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri; background:white;'> <TR>");
    int columnscount = GridView1.Columns.Count;

    for (int j = 0; j < columnscount; j++)
    {


        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<B>");
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(GridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText.ToString());
    }

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<TR>");
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(row[i].ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
    }
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Table>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</font>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

CITY  CONTACT    EMAILID             NAME     ID    NUMBER  LIKE

Comment: The line printing the headers is commented out.

Comment: i am sorry can u poinout which code  ,because if am umcommenting below two codes i am getting  errors   // HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Reports.doc");
       //HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Reports.xlsx");

Comment: `//HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(GridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText.ToString());`

Comment: no it still not working  SELECT Story.City,Story.Contact,Story.UserEmailid,Story.UserName,Story.StoryId,COUNT(Likes.StoryID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM Likes 
                                LEFT JOIN Story ON Likes.StoryId=Story.StoryId and liked between '12/10/2013' and '12/11/2013'
                                GROUP BY Story.StoryId,Story.UserName,Story.UserEmailid,Story.Contact,Story.City order by NumberOfOrders DESC    i am using the below quey to fill the datatable

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void ExporttoExcel(DataTable table)
 {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");
       HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Reports.xls");
       // HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Reports.doc");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<font style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<BR><BR><BR>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri; background:white;'> <TR>");
        int columnscount = GridView_Result.Columns.Count;

        for (int j = 0; j < columnscount; j++)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<B>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(GridView_Result.Columns[j].HeaderText.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</B>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<TR>");
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(row[i].ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Table>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</font>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }



    protected void Btn_Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExporttoExcel(dt);

    }
}
```